Cumulative count cut min/max values in Python different from min/max values in QGIS
I am trying to replicate using Python, what QGIS does to visualize the rasters in the map.
QGIS automatically chooses as contrast enhancement the method Stretch to MinMax. Looking at the Min/Max Settings, the Cumulative count cut is selected with the range being between 2% - 98%.

I saw in this answer that the cumulative count cut method is basically the same than numpy.nanpercentile. So I implemented this function in python:
def cumulative_count_cut(band, min_percentile=2, max_percentile=98):
    min_val = np.nanpercentile(band, min_percentile)
    max_val = np.nanpercentile(band, max_percentile)
    print(min_val,max_val)


I was expecting to the Min and Max values equal or even near the ones in QGIS but this is what I got instead:

Band 04: Min: 0.0 | Max: 1221.0
Band 03: Min: 0.0 | Max: 1430.0
Band 02: Min: 0.0 | Max: 1663.0

Am I missing something? Shouldn't the values be the same?

To compare apples to apples, you might want to use an exact Accuracy in QGIS band rendering settings, not an estimate

@Kasper what do you mean? how do I do that in QGIS? I just want to try and understand how come the min value is different from QGIS. I am not expecting to get exactly the same value but somewhere near.

In your screenshot: change the setting where Estimate is currently written. With Estimate, a quick sampling is used to derive the Min /Max which can introduce some inaccuracies. Not saying you'll get near values, but at least you'll get the exact values that QGIS has as Min/Max according to its methodology

I have found the answer and it was quite easy.Considering that the min value was always 0, I tried to see if by ignoring the 0 values, the min_val would change. And it did! They are not exactly the same, but they are close enough.
Python:

Band 04: Min: 161 | Max: 1958
Band 03: Min: 179 | Max: 1714
Band 02: Min: 122 | Max: 1476

QGIS:

Code:
def cumulative_count_cut(band, min_percentile=2, max_percentile=98):
    """Apply contrast enhancement stretch similar to QGIS"""
    new_band = band[band != 0]
    min_val = np.nanpercentile(new_band, min_percentile)
    max_val = np.nanpercentile(new_band, max_percentile)
    print(min_val,max_val)
    return (band - min_val) / (max_val - min_val + offset) * 255


Before you built something very broken, please do try setting the Accuracy in QGIS. Surely you do not want to always ignore the value 0 when calculating statistics.

@bugmenot123 as you can see in the code, i do not ignore the value 0 when converting the image to Byte. I only ignore the value 0 when getting the percentile for the cumulative count cut. The objective of this question was to try and figure it out how QGIS does this and replicate in python. That is what was done.
